The model trained in PyTorch produces inconsistent predictions for the same image when processed individually versus in a batch
I am noticing a significant difference in model predictions when running predictions on a single image versus the whole dataset. The model, which was trained using PyTorch, gives drastically different predictions for the same image when processed individually versus in a batch. Is there any way to ensure that the predictions are consistent for the same image when processed individually and in a batch?
For single image its [0.37732467 0.2642143 0.35846105]
and for that same image in batch its [0.3185594 0.40971586 0.2717247 ].
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, PreTrainedModel, PretrainedConfig
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

# Number of Features
num_of_features = 128

# Dataset Class
class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {"input_ids": self.X[idx], "labels": self.y[idx]}


# Configuration Class
class SequenceConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    model_type = "sequence_transformer"

    def __init__(self, num_features=num_of_features, num_classes=3, d_model=1024, nhead=4, num_layers=4, dim_feedforward=512, **kwargs):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.nhead = nhead
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dim_feedforward = dim_feedforward
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


# Transformer Model
class SequenceTransformer(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = SequenceConfig

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Linear(config.num_features, config.d_model)
        self.positional_encoding = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, config.d_model))
        encoder_layer = torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=config.d_model, 
            nhead=config.nhead, 
            dim_feedforward=config.dim_feedforward, 
            batch_first=True
        )
        self.transformer_encoder = torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=config.num_layers)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(config.d_model, config.num_classes)

    def forward(self, input_ids, labels=None):
        src = self.embedding(input_ids) + self.positional_encoding
        output = self.transformer_encoder(src)
        logits = self.fc(output)
        probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
            
        return {"loss": loss, "logits": logits, "probs": probs} if labels is not None else logits


# Training Code
config = SequenceConfig()
model = SequenceTransformer(config)

# Training Arguments
    batchSize=32
    numWarmUpSteps=int(np.shape(train_image)[0]/batchSize/numOfBreakpointsPerEpoch/10)
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=path,
        num_train_epochs=1, 
        per_device_train_batch_size=batchSize,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=320,
        warmup_steps=numWarmUpSteps,
        weight_decay=0.1,
        logging_strategy='no',
        eval_strategy="epoch",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
        save_only_model=True,
    )

# Trainer Initialization
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

# Train the Model
train_output = trainer.train()

# Save Model and Training Arguments
trainer.save_model("./SavedModels")
torch.save(training_args, "./SavedModels/training_args.bin")

# Prediction Code
training_args_loaded = torch.load("./SavedModels/training_args.bin")
model_save_path = "./SavedModels/"
model = SequenceTransformer(config).from_pretrained(model_save_path)

trainer = Trainer(model=model, compute_metrics=compute_metrics, args=training_args_loaded)
test_data = np.random.rand(10, num_of_features)  # Example test data
test_predictions = trainer.predict(torch.tensor(test_data, dtype=torch.float32))

# Output Test Predictions
print(test_predictions)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You did not provide any code or model details, so there is nothing to answer here. And why is this tagged keras?
